# Error nested link in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a little problem of link.

I have 2 models nested, one `Faqcategory`and `Faq`.
The route is

```
  resources :faqcategories, :path => 'faqs' do
    resources :faqs, :path => 'question'
  end
```

I can display all the "faqcategories" at http://localhost:3000/faqs/
and all the faqcategory as "questions" at http://localhost:3000/faqs/8

But when I want to go on the show of the question at http://localhost:3000/faqs/8/question/1 , it sends me at http://localhost:3000/faqs/1/question/8
I have set up the view like that:

```
<% @faqs.each do |question| %>
  <%= link_to question.title, faqcategory_faq_path(question), class: "btn btn-rose btn-round" %>
<% end %>
```

In the FaqcateroriesController the "show" is set up like that:

```
def show
  @faqs = @faqcategory.faqs
end
```

How do you think I can solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

```
<% @faqcategory.faqs.each do |question| %>
  <%= link_to question.title, faqcategory_faq_path(question.faqcategory_id, question), class: "btn btn-rose btn-round" %>
<% end %>
```

It was missing "question.faqcategory_id"